# How to send request promise resolve response from another function and that function is call from inside of request promise in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Actual scenario   is  i want  to  return   request promise  response of `test2()`   from `test4()`    function.
because some independent calculation are done in `test4()` and `test2()` can not wait   for `test3()` and `test4()`
so  i again call `test2()`   from `test4()`  with   status flag   but the problem is first request promise  is overwritten in  Memory stack.Is  it possible to send request promise response from another function  rather than that function.

```
var status = false;
(async () => {
   var res = await test1();
   console.log('Hi');
   console.log(res);
})();
async function test1() {
    console.log('Call to test2');
    var restest1 = await test2();
    console.log('All Finished', restest1);
    return restest1;
}
function test2() {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {

        if (status) {
            resolve('success');  
        }
        else {

            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('Call to test3');
                test3();
            }, 5000);

        }
    });
}
function test3() {
    test4();
}
function test4() {
    status = true;
    test2();
    console.log('test4 finished');
}
```

The problem is `console.log('Hi'); console.log(res);` not working

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? The output is generated...

Comment: it is working properly

Comment: `test3()` is a function that only call `test4`, isn't redundant?

Comment: you don't resolve the promise in `test2` when `status` is not true. So you just create a promise for nothing. Also why an `async` constructor? That is useless. What exactly is the output you expect?

Comment: var res =await test1();  this waiting  for   test1()   response inside test1()  it call test2() with promise   so test1()   wiating for  test2() response but   i can send  test2() response only test4()  execution    so that  after  code  var res =await test1(); not working

Comment: can you just give the sequence in which you want to execute your funtions?

Comment: Also, `status` is a bad name for a global variable. If you run it in a browser, it conflicts with `window.status`, which is always a string. So you actually set it to "false" , which is a truthy value.

Comment: @krishnasapkal First  test1()  is   call  so console.log('Hi');  console.log(res); is work only after  test1()  result is getback. test1() is call test2()  and test2() is   request promise   when  we  resolve() then   test2() return back the result to  test1()  but the problem is i want to call test3()  from test2() and test3() call to test4()  so   some calculation are  perform inside  test4()  after that  i want resovle() or returm  promise of test2(). I can not use  chain of promise or   Synchronous  execution flow from test2()  to test4()

Comment: Is your output supposed to be "Call to test2", "Call to test3", "test4 finished", "All Finished success", "Hi", "success" in order?

Comment: @krishnasapkal yes

Comment: OK, I'll try to give a fix in a moment

Comment: @krishnasapkal    test2()  can not wait for  test3() and test4()   means   can not use   synchronous   function call(means
write a  promise or async/await  for  test3() and test4())

Comment: @sam  could you please share your FB profile or Linkedin profile because i am new in Node.js so i can ask some doubt or knowledge from you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and the desired output, I have a quick fix based on your current code structure. The idea is to pass the resolve function along until you really want to call it. So, when you call test2 inside test4 passing the initial resolve function, actually the original promise is resolved and returned. Does it answer your question or I miss your point?

```js
(async () => {
   var res = await test1();
   console.log('Hi');
   console.log(res);
})();
async function test1() {
    console.log('Call to test2');
    var restest1 = await test2();
    console.log('All Finished', restest1);
    return restest1;
}
function test2(resolve) {
    return new Promise(async _resolve => {
        if (resolve) {
            resolve('success');  
        }
        else {

            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('Call to test3');
                test3(_resolve);
            }, 5000);

        }
    });
}
function test3(resolve) {
    test4(resolve);
}
function test4(resolve) {
    test2(resolve);
    console.log('test4 finished');
}
```

Comment: Thanks   very much.I tried  to assign whole  request promise to   a variable   after that  i check  like   variable.resolve   but it shows   an error